# Can XSS be introduced by changing the language encoding?

Tags: security, utf-8, xss

Lets say I have a web application that is using Latin1 or some default English language encoding.  I want to change the application to use UTF-8 or perhaps another language encoding.   Can you **prove** that this change will introduce XSS?

This is not a PHP specific question,  but in PHP can you show a case where `htmlspecialchars($var,ENT_QUOTES);` is vulnerable to XSS and `htmlspecialchars($var,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629#section-10):

> **10. Security Considerations**
>
> Implementers of UTF-8 need to consider
> the security aspects of how they
> handle illegal UTF-8 sequences.  It is
> conceivable that in some circumstances
> an attacker would be able to exploit
> an incautious UTF-8 parser by sending
> it an octet sequence that is not
> permitted by the UTF-8 syntax.
>
> A particularly subtle form of this
> attack can be carried out against a
> parser which performs
> security-critical validity checks
> against the UTF-8 encoded form of its
> input, but interprets certain illegal
> octet sequences as characters.  For
> example, a parser might prohibit the
> NUL character when encoded as the
> single-octet sequence 00, but
> erroneously allow the illegal
> two-octet sequence C0 80 and interpret
> it as a NUL character.  Another
> example might be a parser which
> prohibits the octet sequence 2F 2E 2E
> 2F ("/../"), yet permits the illegal
> octet sequence 2F C0 AE 2E 2F.  This
> last exploit has actually been used in
> a widespread virus attacking Web
> servers in 2001; thus, the security
> threat is very real.

So it's vitally important to ascertain that your data *is* valid UTF-8.

But once you have done this, security concerns related to the encoding are minimal.  All HTML special characters are in ASCII, and UTF-8 like ISO-8859-1 is fully ASCII-compatible.  `htmlspecialchars` will behave the way you expect.

There is more of a concern with non-ASCII-compatible encodings.  For example, in [GB18030](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_18030), the ASCII bytes 0x30 and above can occur within the encoding of a multi-byte character.  The HYPHEN character `‐` (U+2010) is encoded as A9 **5C**, which includes an ASCII backslash.  This makes it more difficult to properly handle backslash escaping, inviting [SQL injection](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/8.1.4_et._al._Security_Release_FAQ).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a silly example that cheats by misusing `htmlspecialchars` from how you intended.

```
<?php
$s = htmlspecialchars($_GET['x'], ENT_QUOTES);
$s_utf8 = htmlspecialchars($_GET['x'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

if(!empty($s))
  print "default: " . $_GET['x'] . "<br>\n";

if(!empty($s_utf8))
  print "utf8: " . $_GET['x'] . "<br>\n"
?>
```

Submit any XSS payload and add an invalid UTF-8 byte, e.g.

`http://site/silly.php?x=<script>alert(0)</script>%fe`

`htmlspecialchars` bails on an invalid UTF-8 byte sequence and returns an empty string. Printing the `$_GET` value is an obvious hole, but I do have a point to make.

In short, you're going to get byte-by-byte checks with Latin1 and UTF-8 so I'm not aware of a language-dependent example where `htmlspecialchars` will miss a dangerous byte in one encoding, but not another.

The point of my example is that your question was more general (and perhaps a bit too vague) to the dangers of XSS when changing encoding schemes. When content starts dealing with different multi-byte encoding then developers may foul up validation filters based on `strchr()`, `strlen()`, or similar checks that aren't multi-byte aware and might be thwarted by a %00 in the payload. (Hey, some devs still hold to using regexes to parse and sanitize HTML.)

In principle, I think the two example lines in the question have equal security as far as switching encoding. In practice, there are still plenty of ways to make other mistakes with ambiguous encoding.

Comment: I guess another point I could have made is "Know your error handling" -- it can get pretty tricky dealing with invalid byte codes or being surprised by unexpected behaviors.

Comment: yeah I agree, other functions can error out and return an empty string if you try and pass them an array `?pass[]=1`,  but i didn't know about invalid UTF8,  thats cool.